# Messed up desktop

Tags: unity, launcher, shutdown

When the cursor hovers over launcher on left side of desktop the display flashes and the launcher disappears.  It returns but the same thing happens every time I try to open an application.  The same thing happens when I try to shut down by selecting shut down from top bar.  The only way I can shut down is with a command in a terminal.  I reinstalled operating system (16.04 LTS) and it works fine until I run updates.

Comment: I do not know what is happening. Probably a buggy update. Try not to update the "ubuntu-desktop" package by "un-checking" it in Update Manager. You can install every other update, but try not to install "ubuntu-desktop". I had that happen to me when I installed the Ubuntu Netbook Desktop (Unity Desktop) package on my Ubuntu 10.10 Desktop.

Comment: Have you tried the latest updates?

Answer (score 0):

This is [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1735594) (#1735594) that was reported December 1, 2017. Numerous bug reports have been filed, but marked as duplicates.

According to a comment on bug [#1741447](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1741447/comments/39), this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/pkppa/) works, which many say fixed the issue. The main bug report also makes mention of this fix in reference to bug #1741447. Users can update their system with unsupported packages from this untrusted PPA by adding `ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa` to their system's Software Sources.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa
sudo apt-get update
```

This solution works for me, and is probably going to become the official fix, or will be incorporated into an update, if it hasn't already. More information can be found in the given links.

If you are affected, let them know by marking you are affected at the [main bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1735594).